# WKInterfaceObjects not load content

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm stack on this issue since 2 hours. I'm working on a watch App, I display some content in a table view, on row selection I push a ne WKInterfaceController and pass through a context with some data ( String and image). I can log this content, but I'm not able to load the image inside the WKInterfaceImage and the text inside the WKInterfaceLabel. this code run inside awakeWithContext. Any idea?

```
  _myObject = (MyModel*)context;
NSLog(@"NAME %@", _myObject.name);

// Configure interface objects here.
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: _myObject.imageData];
if (image == nil) {
    [_myImageV setImageNamed:@"DefaultImage"];
}else{
    [_myImageV setImage:image];
}

  NSString* text = _myObject.name;

  [_labelText setText:text];
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the portion of code you've shared. If you're able to verify that the `MyModel` object is making it across, I'd double-check that your IBOutlets have been properly configured in Interface Builder. Perhaps you're setting values for disconnected controls.

Comment: Try to debug it, we can't help you based on what you give to us. Just like what Mike said, there is no obvious errors.

Comment: I solved it. There was a Table inside the controller that was cover the rest of the interface. Stupid error :(. Thanks for your help